# Мультиключ для словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Есть ли какие-то способы создать словарь такой, чтобы к одному значению подходило несколько ключей, без создания доп. значений в словаре, пример работы:

```
dict = {(a, b, c) : value}
dict[a] == value
dict[b] == value
dict[c] == value
```

Без создания словаря с {a : value, b : value, ...}

Comment: Но зачем? . . .

Comment: Душа требует :)

Comment: Такая душа рискует попасть в ад

Comment: Создать класс с 3мя свойствами и использовать его как ключ ?

Comment: Ну, свойств может быть не три, а можете привести пример кода, как вы это видите?

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, кейс, где это требуется? Вариант есть, но неизвестно, подойдёт ли он Вам.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/multi_key_dict/

Comment: простите а в чём проблема ? {x:'value' for x in range(5)}

Comment: как записывать новые ключи в такой словарь? дедупликация по id(value)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смысл в том, то в этом словаре меняю ключ и значение местами. Так как значение не всегда хешируемо, то переношу его в отдельный словарик и связываю по id объекта.

Вот такой базовый вариант у меня получился

```
class MultiKeyDict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__keys = {}
        self.__values = {}
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        value_id = id(value)
        try:
# старое значение и любой ключ
            self.__keys[value_id].append(key)
            return
        except KeyError:
            pass
# старый ключ и новое значение, связанные ключи тоже изменяются
# можно вместо удаления связи переносить ключ из одного сета в другой - переписать тут
        self.__values[value_id] = value
        for vid, keys in self.__keys.items():
            if key in keys:
                self.__keys.pop(vid)
                self.__values.pop(vid)
                self.__keys[value_id] = self.__keys.get(value_id, set() ) + keys
                break
        else:
# новое значение, новый ключ
            self.__keys[value_id] = set([key]) 
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for vid, keys in self.__keys():
            if key in keys:
                return self.__values[vid]
        raise KeyError(key)
    def items(self):
# чтоб работать с этим в циклах
        for vid in self.__keys.keys():
            yield (tuple(self.__keys[vid]), self.__values[vid])
    def __repr__(self):
# соберем из двух словарей один
        return repr(dict(self.items()))
```

Вроде условиям вопроса соответствует

```
>>> a=MultiKeyDict()
>>> a[2]='hello'
>>> a[5]='hello'
>>> a
{(2, 5): 'hello'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать вот такой вариант:

```
class MultiDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self.__dict[key].append(value)
        except KeyError:
            self.__dict[key] = [value]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict[key]
```

Comment: Автору вопроса ведь нужно наоборот -- чтобы ключи можно было задавать как кортеж и получать значение по одному из элементов в ключе-кортеже. Кст, то, что у вас можно сделать через `defaultdict(list)` :)

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне есть встроенные возможности для создания своих типов-контейнеров, работающих по аналогии со встроенными контейнерами (`list`, `dict`, `tuple`): [Emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types). Следовательно, можно создать новый тип, наполнить его нужными методами и в результате получить требуемую функциональность.

**Идея моего решения следующая**:

На примере `mlt_dict['a', 'b', 'c'] = "green"`

- Из полученных ключей выбираем один, главный и записываем под этим ключом значение в словарь со значениями.

  ```
    {
        'a' : "green"
    }
  ```
- Во второй словарь пишем все ключи со ссылкой на главный ключ.

  ```
    {
        'a' : 'a',
        'b' : 'a',
        'c' : 'a'
    }
  ```
- В третьем словаре держим главные ключи со ссылкой на все ключи данного значения. Это понадобиться при удалении элемента, чтобы удалить все его ключи из второго словаря (основано на предположении, что при удалении элемента по любому из ключей, удаляется сам элемент и все ключи ссылающиеся на него).

  ```
    {
        'a' : ('a', 'b', 'c')
    }
  ```

На данный момент новый тип поддерживает добавление, удаление, проверку на наличие (`x in dct`), распечатку содержимого объекта. Проверок не добавлял, чтобы не загромождать решение и не тратить время - этот код просто демонстрация идеи.

```
class Multi_key_dict:
    def __init__(self, *items):
        self.values_dict = {}
        self.minor_to_major_links = {}
        self.major_to_minor_links = {}

        for keys, value in items:
            self[keys] = value

    def __setitem__(self, keys, value):
        major_key = keys[0]

        for key in keys:
            self.minor_to_major_links[key] = major_key

        self.major_to_minor_links[major_key] = keys
        self.values_dict[major_key] = value
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        major_key = self.minor_to_major_links[key]
        return self.values_dict[major_key]

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        major_key = self.minor_to_major_links[key]
        del self.values_dict[major_key]

        for key in self.major_to_minor_links[major_key]:
            del self.minor_to_major_links[key]

        del self.major_to_minor_links[major_key]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.minor_to_major_links

    def __repr__(self):
        mlt_dct = ', '.join (f"{keys} : {repr(self.values_dict[major])}" for major, keys in self.major_to_minor_links.items())
        return f"Multi_key_dict({mlt_dct})"
```

**Тестирование**

```
mlt_dict = Multi_key_dict(
                            (('a', 'b', 'c'), "green"),
                            (('d', 'e', 'f'), "red"),
                            (('g', 'h', 'i'), "blue"),
                            ((1, 2, 3), "violet"),
                            ((8, 9, 10), ("one", "two", "three"))
                        )

mlt_dict['x', 'y', 'z'] = "orange"

print(mlt_dict['a'])
print(mlt_dict['b'])
print(mlt_dict['c'])

print(mlt_dict['d'])
print(mlt_dict['e'])
print(mlt_dict['f'])

print(mlt_dict['g'])
print(mlt_dict['h'])
print(mlt_dict['i'])
print()

print("{:#^40s}".format("print(mlt_dict)"))
print(mlt_dict)
print()

print("{:#^40s}".format("del mlt_dict['a']"))
del mlt_dict['a']
print()

print("{:#^40s}".format("print(mlt_dict)"))
print(mlt_dict)
print()

print("{:#^40s}".format("print('a' in mlt_dict)"))
print('a' in mlt_dict)
print()
```

**Результат**

```
green
green
green
red
red
red
blue
blue
blue

############print(mlt_dict)#############
Multi_key_dict(('a', 'b', 'c') : 'green', ('d', 'e', 'f') : 'red', ('g', 'h', 'i') : 'blue', (1, 2, 3) : 'violet', (8, 9, 10) : ('one', 'two', 'three'), ('x', 'y', 'z') : 'orange')

###########del mlt_dict['a']############

############print(mlt_dict)#############
Multi_key_dict(('d', 'e', 'f') : 'red', ('g', 'h', 'i') : 'blue', (1, 2, 3) : 'violet', (8, 9, 10) : ('one', 'two', 'three'), ('x', 'y', 'z') : 'orange')

#########print('a' in mlt_dict)#########
False
```

Comment: Сетитем мне что-то не нравится у вас

Comment: @eri Всё как описано в объяснении - выбираем главный ключ, пишем значение с этим ключом в первый словарь, затем все ключи со ссылкой на главный ключ во второй словарь, затем все в третий. Как база данных - один ко многим, много к одному.